# Camera Hand Mouse/Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, camera, gestures

Is there software out there that lets me control the computer purely through gestures using a webcam?

I understand that it might need to have novel ways to process what used to be "keyboard input" (as well as mouse input), and I'd like to see what's out there.